# Apache/PHP open connection to another websver - Web RDP

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to setup a web terminal server with dual factor authentication. I have a PHP web application on Apache that would let a user login using dual factor authentication. This part works just fine.

Eg: 10.3.80.167/Auth_App

Then I have a Microsoft Windows 2008 server with Web RDP running in IIS.

Eg: 10.3.80.169/webrdp

10.3.80.167 is open to the internet and people can log. What I want to do is to use as a additional level of security to web RDP.

Users will log into 10.3.80.167/Auth_App, and when they log in they'd have a button that would take them to 10.3.80.169/webrdp and be able to login. However 10.3.80.169/webrdp is not open to the internet.

So the bottom line is, I have one web server that is connected to the internet. There is second web server that isn't, but first web server has access to it. I'm trying to let people log in to the first web server and verify them, then they can access a website on the second web server via the first one.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to do. How do I archive this with Apache and PHP? (Auth App verifies a user and creates a session)

Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing both applications on the iiS and use a cookie